# Please help me debug this error message I get at the console

Tags: symfony, twig

When I run this command `php app/console translation:update es GWDAdminBundle --force  --prefix="__"` at the terminal I get the following error message:

```
[Twig_Error_Syntax]                                                                     
Unexpected token "name" of value "View" ("end of print statement" expected) at line 31
```

I don't which file is throwing this error, when I look at the log there is nothing remotely close to this, I suspect that it is one of my view files but how do I begin looking? Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you have forgotten to close some block in one of your twig templates. So, the twig parser is expecting to get an 'endblock' (or something like this) keyword but got 'name' string. 
I think you have to check out your templates.

Comment: Try running `app/console twig:lint src/`, it could help you locate the error.

Comment: Excellent! This helped me tremendously! I had done a find and replace across many files, which I messed up a lot of them. This saved me, just another trick I've learned, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to **kix**! I was able to debug all of my twig files with the following command:

```
php app/console twig:lint src/
```

Comment: Since Symfony 3 it's `php app/console lint:twig src/`